# Can't get background image to appear for bootstrap jumbotron

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've searched this and tried the things from the answers I have found but I cannot seem to get the jumbotron background image to appear. This is what I have right now. I have tried using an image from my images folder with no luck and currently trying a link with the same result. I've tried div.jumbotron, tried giving it another name, and tried getting rid of the other background properties.

I'm pretty new to bootstrap and HTML and not sure if my problem is because I'm overlooking something that I'm doing wrong or something else.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">Top Page</h1>
    <p class="lead">Simple Bootstrap template.</p>
  </div>

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.com/photos/kjERLXaHjXc);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; }
```

Comment: works for me : https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/cqkw9y5g/1/ validate the image.

Comment: The URL that you are using is a HTML page, not an image: https://unsplash.com/photos/kjERLXaHjXc

Comment: this is correct img url : https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472157592780-9e5265f17f8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please add correct image url.**

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472157592780-9e5265f17f8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Top Page</h1>
  <p class="lead">Simple Bootstrap template.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked the link. Seems like you have entered the wrong link.
This might be the photo.
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472157592780-9e5265f17f8f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80

Comment: This link is identical to the link in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743721/12695027) by [Rayees AC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13368658)